# how to update kendo grid aggregate automatically

Tags: kendo-grid

I made a table by kendo grid.
Test column' value is [#: Unitsinstock * Unitprice#].
but,When Unitprice value Changs , test column value
and Unitprice aggregate sum , Test aggregate sum can't update automatically.

Demo:https://dojo.telerik.com/UTOnuN

how to update kendo grid aggregate automatically?

Thx

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I made a demo for more details.thx.

Comment: @rubyblaze, typically is better if you include the code in here or if you use SO possibility of using its own code snippets. Better reducing dependencies from others.